# mongoDb embedded query to find list of data

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have the following embedded data And I am trying to get all the transactions which have a same week number for a particular saved account based on the `accountId`. I tried the following query but it returns an empty array.

```
savingsAccount.find({accountId: "123456789012345678", transactions: {weekNumber: 32}})
```

Any Ideas? Thanks so much in advance.

```
    "savingsAccount":
    {
        "_id": "598cb8686739d49a6f59dbb4",
        "accountId": "123456789012345678",
        "__v": 2,
        "transactions": [
            {
                "_id": "598cb8a86739d49a6f59dbb5",
                "amount": 1234,
                "weekNumber": 32,
                "date": "2017-08-10T19:48:56.347Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "598cbb70a4a8f89c18309d87",
                "amount": 1234,
                "weekNumber": 32,
                "date": "2017-08-10T20:00:48.241Z"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ...

```
savingsAccount.find({
    accountId: "123456789012345678", 
    'transactions.weekNumber': 32
})
```

... will return all documents for which `accountId` is "123456789012345678" and the `weekNumber` attribute of at least one subdocument in the `transactions` array is 32.

Your original query returned no matches because the second predicate (`transactions: {weekNumber: 32}`) was attempting to match elements of the `transactions` array with the value: `{weekNumber: 32}` and, since that only represents **part** of a transactions document, no match was found.

**Edit 1**: if you want to go further than this to only return the subdocuments in the `transactions` array which have `weekNumber=32` then you have to [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) (available in versions >= 3.2). Here's an example:

```
db.savingsAccount.aggregate([
    {$match: { accountId: "123456789012345678" }},
    {$project: {
        accountId: 1,
        __v: 1,
        transactions: {$filter: {
            input: '$transactions',
            as: 't',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$t.weekNumber', 32]}
        }}
    }}
])
```

This will return all documents for which `accountId` is "123456789012345678" and the `weekNumber` attribute of at least one subdocument in the `transactions` array is 32 and for each matched document it will filter the `transactions` array such that only those subdocuments having `weekNumber=32` are returned.

Comment: I tried the above query but it returns all transactions which matches the accountId.

Comment: Yes, because the predicates match on the document not on the array element so the above query returns all documents which match those predicates and it returns the whole of those documents because no projection is specified. You can project on the returned documents to limit the elements of the transacitons sub document, I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: That works!! Thank you so much for the information :)